# How can I create a team in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

How can I create my own team in Pokemon Go. Can I join any other team? If yes, how?

I've been playing for the last 4 days and I am not able to understand the team feature completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create your own team.

You can only join one of the three teams available.

They are Team Mystic (blue), Team Instinct (yellow) and Team Valor (red).

You can join one of these 3 teams after tapping on a gym once reaching trainer level 5.

Comment: So if I'm from team blue and someone in my hood , defender of a gym is from team bleu, I only can support him but not challange the gym?

Comment: you can train the gym, where you fight all the gym's pokemon with a single pokemon of yours in order to increase the prestige and level of the gym. You can also add a pokemon to defend the gym.

Comment: Ok, so that means regarding my question yes or no?!

Comment: That means, regarding your question, no.